# Lambda Node.js require from a sub folder

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that I am trying to shuffle around to make it more organize.  I am able to require a file by doing this `const db = require('./db.js')`, the problem is when I move db.js into a folder called "db", and changed my code to `const db = require('./db/db.js')` and even try `const db = require('/db /db.js')` but both get an error of db.js not found, is there another way to require a sub directory?

Comment: It should be working with `require('./db/db.js')` Make sure db.js is exporting correctly using `module.exports` statement